What is the desired percentage of the whole of Special B in a 5 gallon British Brown Ale brew
Working on a recipe for a British Brown Ale. At current state, I have my Special B at 7.4% of the whole grain bill. Is there a publicized range available where I can find what the desired level is? It's a 5 gal batch.

It really depends on what your goal is.
In my experience, the dark fruit flavors are discernable at 5% (assuming no other strongly-flavored grains). I think you are quite safe going to 7.4% - the distinctive flavors will be noticeable but not overpowering.
Remember, this is a crystal/caramel malt, so you don't want to go too crazy with it.
I have had very good luck with Special B in my Belgian Dubbel (6% Special B) and Quad (3% Special B). It was a real delight in my most recent Barleywine (5.9% Special B @ 14.1%ABV - yikes!), adding an interesting complexity.

Thank you Rob! I feel more comfortable now with my grain bill. Will get it ordered and brew away.
